# А Вам не режет слух: нэт или нет?

Tags: транскрипция

У меня у знакомого дочь - первоклассница. И вот я услышал, как она, пытаясь объяснить папе что-то про увиденное только что по телевизору, говорит: "Нет, я про ту рекламу, которая была сразу после грузинской...". На немой вопрос, застывший у меня в глазах, знакомый ответил, что это она про "ищите ответ на сайте GEPATITU.NET (у них и вправду это звучит, как бы пополиткорректней выразится, несколько с акцентом - как гепатиту.НЭТ :-))".

И я подумал, а как на самом деле правильней в данном случае - "нет", что и по смыслу подходит больше - гепатиту нет!, или "нэт", что в переводе с английского СЕТЬ, как и должно звучать это расширение, если бы не было этого дательного падежа "нет (кому? чему?) гепатиту, на конце "у" (!)", ведь не зря же кто-то креативил это название для сайта ГЕПАТИТУ.НЕТ?

А Вы что по этому поводу думаете?

Answer (score 6):

Тот кто креативил - молодец, название у сайта хорошее. Домен ".net" читается как [нэт] и ради этого сайта менять произношение не стоит, что тут подразумевается понятно и так.

Comment: Учитывая, что теперь возможно зарегистрировать домен с кириллическими символами, например, "гепатиту.нет", то я вообще не вижу осмысленности в вопросе =) А игра слов - всегда хорошо

Answer (score 0):

А что такое "правильно"?
У нас что, есть утвержденные правила чтения иностранных букв в рекламных слоганах?
С точки зрения действенности рекламы, конечно, НЭТ. Иначе или не поймут, или внимание не задержат.

Кстати, "креатив" этот я слышу уже почитай лет 25. С первых выходов в интернет, который тогда и интернетом-то еще не был.